# Send image from Flutter to callable cloud function

Tags: json, image, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I have callable cloud function used to register new Users. These users should also have a profile pic. I want to handle the whole registration process in my function and not from my client, so I want to send the image picked by the user to the function and upload it from there.

How do I send the image in the json data argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to upload the image from the client side. There is no way to send image data from client to `Could Function` without uploading. You can do following things:

- Upload the image from the client side and save the download url to `Cloud Firestore`.
- Use a `Cloud Function Trigger` to execute `onDoumentCreated()` and
  get the newly uploaded image url. Here you can do many things like
  cropping or compressing, generating thumbnails as you want.
- Complete the registration from `Cloud Function`.